How to type hints class property with mypy
I writer a classproperty like this MRE.Except for mypy, everything else is ok(There is no problem during runtime).
from typing import Any, Callable, Generic, Self, TypeVar

_R = TypeVar('_R')


class classproperty(Generic[_R]):
    def __init__(self, method: Callable[..., _R]):
        self.fget = method

    def __get__(self, _instance: Any, cls: Any) -> _R:
        return self.fget(cls)


_T = TypeVar('_T')


class Demo(Generic[_T]):
    def __init__(self, inner: _T):
        self._inner = inner

    @property
    def child_self(self) -> _T:
        return self._inner


class Base:
    @classproperty
    def query(cls) -> Demo[Self]:
        return Demo(cls())  # type: ignore

    @classmethod
    def query_method(cls) -> Demo[Self]:
        return Demo(cls())  # type: ignore


class A(Base):
    id = 1


# eventhing is ok
print(A.query_method().child_self.id)
# mypy error: "Self" has no attribute "id"  [attr-defined]
print(A.query.child_self.id)


Mypy: 1.13.0
Python: 3.12.1
How to add type hints correctly, fixed mypy error. Or any other syntax classproperty. Can`t change Base.query, this syntax is used in too many places.

Any chance you could come up with an MRE that doesn't require sqlalchemy?

@Samwise updated

There might be something wrong with how mypy analyses descriptor decorators combined with function signatures. Here's a workaround (mypy playground):
from typing import ClassVar

...

class Base:
    query: ClassVar[classproperty[Demo[Self]]] = classproperty(lambda cls: Demo(cls()))
    ...

reveal_type(A.query_method().child_self.id)  # int
reveal_type(A.query.child_self.id)           # int


Note: @classproperty implementations with the descriptor protocol are very buggy, and you should avoid them.
